# Como ejecuto un into temp dentro de java

Tags: java, sql, template

1.- creo una tabla temporal llamada (tmp_llaves):

```
   String consulta = "select unique dserie, documento, cliente"
                + "      from cli_relacion_filiales"
                + "      where scontab is null "
                + "      into temp tmp_llaves;";
```

2.- necesitó utilizar esta tabla (tmp_llaves) dentro de la segunda consulta:

```
  String consulta1 = "select r.*"
                + "       from redoc_movims r, dbdatosnomina@soprade:nomcontratos n, tmp_llaves t"
                + "      where  r.nota = n.contidempl "
                + "      and contidempr <> 1 "
                + "      and t.dserie = r.nvadserie "
                + "      and t.documento = r.nvodocumento "
                + "      and t.cliente = r.cliente;";
```

Lo ejecuto de la siguiente manera:

```
            PreparedStatement sel_stmt = igconnmas.prepareStatement(consulta);
            mrc = sel_stmt.executeQuery();

           if (mrc.next()) {
                Statement nuevostmt = igconnmas.createStatement();
               ResultSet mrc2 = sel_stmt.executeQuery(consulta1);
            }
```

pero me sale este error:`introducir el código aquí`
java.sql.SQLException: Method only for queries

Comment: Estás modificando tu base de datos creando una tabla temporal, por lo que no es correcto usar `executeQuery`. Usa en su lugar `execute` en tu primera consulta.

Comment: me funciono perfecto te gradesco